# WIX: how to dynamically update html embed dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, velo

Currently I have an Embed HTML Wix element, containing a map that dynamically adds information based on the country selected. But, the information goes beyond the height of the frame that Wix assigns it - how do I dynamically update the height of the embed as needed? (I've looked into velo but found no way to alter element dimensions...)

video to demonstrate problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1fRoCWHJJw&ab_channel=TarioYou

```js
function handleMapClick(event) {
                        var heightRequired = 0

                        const countryId = event.target.id
                        const countryName = event.target.class
                        const people = countryData[countryId]

                        document.getElementById('country-welcome-title').innerHTML = 'Welcome to ' + countryId

                        if (!people) {
                            document.getElementById('country-info').innerHTML = `No info yet: ${countryId}`
                            return
                        }

                        const peopleCount = Object.keys(people).length

                        // document.getElementById('country-info').innerHTML =
                        // info || 'No data available for this country.' + countryId

                        const parentList = document.createElement('ul')

                        for (const person in people) {
                            const personData = people[person]

                            const parentBullet = document.createElement('li')

                            const position = document.createElement('h2')
                            position.textContent = personData.position
                            const location = document.createElement('p')
                            location.textContent = personData.location
                            const description = document.createElement('p')
                            description.textContent = personData.description

                            const socials = personData.socials

                            const socialsArray = document.createElement('div') // socials array
                            for (const social in socials) {
                                console.log(socials[social])

                                const linkParent = document.createElement('a')
                                linkParent.setAttribute('href', socials[social])
                                const socialImg = document.createElement('img')
                                socialImg.setAttribute('src', imgLinks[social])
                                socialImg.setAttribute('width', '40')

                                linkParent.appendChild(socialImg)
                                socialsArray.appendChild(linkParent)
                            }

                            parentBullet.appendChild(position)
                            parentBullet.appendChild(location)
                            parentBullet.appendChild(description)
                            parentBullet.appendChild(socialsArray)

                            parentList.appendChild(parentBullet)

                            heightRequired += 30
                        }
                        document.getElementById('country-info').appendChild(parentList)
                        $w('#section2').postMessage(heightRequired)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check this nice little script :
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/master
To avoid a useless npm install with dozens of useless files, just get one of the js files in the js directory (iframeResizer.js or iframeResizer.min.js) and load it in your html. ie :

```html
<style>
    iframe { 
        width: 1px;
        min-width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://anotherdomain.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
<script>
  iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#myIframe')
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeResizer.min.js" defer></script>
```

You will need jQuery to be loaded to use this little library.

iframe styling is for iOS compatibility